# Increase thickness in a matplotlib annotation double sided arrow

Tags: matplotlib

The `width` parameter works fine for a single sided arrow but I get an error when using a double sided arrow.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x));
plt.annotate('', xy=(3.2, 0), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(5.9, 0), textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=3))
```

This works fine and results in this plot: 
[image]

The code also works for a double sided arrow with no width specified:

```
plt.annotate('', xy=(3.2, 0), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(5.9, 0), textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', arrowstyle='<->'))
```

[image]

But for a double arrow with width:

```
plt.annotate('', xy=(3.2, 0), xycoords='data',
             xytext=(5.9, 0), textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', width=3, arrowstyle='<->'))
```

results in the matplotlib error: "AttributeError: Unknown property width"

Comment: i think you want "linewidth"

Comment: That did the trick. I'm not crazy though right? Seems like the lingo should be unified.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', lw=3, arrowstyle='<->')
```